# Get form always redirects to the home page

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using TYPO3 6.2.0. 
I created a form search for news, here is the code :

```
<f:form object="{search}" name="search" pageUid="{settings.listPid}" method="get">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="recherche" class="hors-champ">{f:translate(key:'search-texte-label')}</label>
        <f:form.textfield property="subject" class="text-search" id="recherche"/>
        <label for="recherche" class="hors-champ">{f:translate(key:'search-Categorie-label')}</label>
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.bouton_select_news" />

        <span></span>
        <f:form.submit value="{f:translate(key:'search-start')}" class="bt-search"/>

      </fieldset>
    </f:form>
```

The problem is that every time a execute the form, i got redirected to the home page, even though the action of the form contains the good value :

```
<form method="get" name="search" action="index.php?id=56&amp;tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&amp;cHash=d4f1472e52ea8a990f34bb9ad93a3b9f">
```

I have a little solution for the problem, when i add a hidden field id in the form it works :

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{settings.listPid}" />
```

But how come, in the other sites, i have the exact same code without the hidden field i just mentionned, and it works ?

Thanks

Comment: shooting ... "page not found handler?"

Comment: I don't know! How can i find this information ?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem at work and we solved it using JS.

Our form worked perfectly when using POST as method but redirected us to the homepage when we used GET.
Our form looks like this

```
<f:form pageUid="your_pageUid" method="get" action="your_action" controller="your_controller" extensionName="your_extension" noCacheHash="true" pluginName="your_plugin" name="newSearch" object="{newSearch}" id="your_id">
```

and contained only a single textfield
and a button

follwoing JS catches the form before it gets send and redirects the user to the Search:

```
$('#your_form_id').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var input = $(this).find('your_inputfield_id');
  var uri = $(this).attr('action');
  uri += '&' + input.attr('name') + '=' + input.val();      
  window.location.href = uri;
})
```